# Should the site opt out of Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion

Each December, the developers run a game / enhancement / treasure hunt that involves hats on avatars.

- http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com

The event will run from 19 December 2016 up to and including 08 January 2017. The above site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

If anyone has a reason why we should hate hats as a site as opposed to individuals, an answer here is a great place to make that case.

Comment: I like the hats ⭅:)

Comment: +1 for the question - nicely balanced... but you know the answer - **Nuuuu... we love hats!!** ;)

Comment: I can't figure out who would down-vote this question... It basically asks a simple yes/no question as a community, with a solo opt-out clause. What could possibly deserve a down-vote? If you want or don't want hats, vote on one or more of the answers.

Comment: Don't worry too much @Tetsujin - on meta people down vote things they don't want to see enacted. So a down vote here = an up vote for the no answer.

Comment: Hokay - fair enough. I guess it just seems simpler to vote on the yes/no answers to me ;)

Comment: If I'm reading the "I Am Your Father" hat correctly, then answering or voting on this question that you don't want hats is worth... a hat.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Hats are the best and we want hats.

A vote for this answer is a vote for no.

Comment: Does that include asshats? ;-)

Comment: No one wants more ass unless they specifically ask for it, no?

Answer (score 12):

Why should we opt out Winter Bash? Its always a fun game. Even developers need a little fun some times.

I Love Hats.

Comment: I couldn't think of a reason, but I wanted to check in case there were some.

Answer (score -5):

Just for some balance on the voting [& not a reflection of my personal opinion] let's see how much activity this one can generate.

I don't mind down-votes.

## We do not want hats. Please opt-out.

Comment: NO FUN ALLOWED! 

Comment: ⤜( ⸟ ෴ ⸟ )⤏ none.

Comment: Users have been proven to pay more hattention to questions during Winter Bash. Which is bad.

Comment: -1 great answer but you don't need so much hattitude

Comment: Taking one for the team :D